# Python & Selenium: How do I check if I liked a post on instagram or not?

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to first locate (via xpath) and click the first post of a profile. Then I wanted to locate the "heart"-element and see the value of its aria-label because in the aria-label there is either "Like" or "Unlike". The problem is now that I get the following error when trying to locate the "heart"-element:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div/span/svg"}

I tried so much but somehow I am stuck at this simple problem...
My code is:

```
def foo(self):
    self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    element = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div/span/svg")
    text = element.get_attribute("aria-label")
    print(text)
```

I appriciate your help very much x)

Answer (score 2):

```
def foo(self):
    self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    element = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div/span/svg")
    color = element.get_attribute("fill")
    if color == '#ed4956':
        return "Liked"
    return 'Not Liked'
```

This works. It checks based on the color of the heart svg.